# Three dimensional Fourier Transform of a rational function

Tags: complex-analysis, fourier-transform

Given $s\in(0,2)$, can we find an explicit representation for the (three-dimensional) Fourier transform of the function
$$f_s(x):=\frac{|x|^s}{1+|x|^2},$$
or at least some pointwise bound?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

$\newcommand{\bbx}[1]{\,\bbox[15px,border:1px groove navy]{\displaystyle{#1}}\,}
 \newcommand{\braces}[1]{\left\lbrace\,{#1}\,\right\rbrace}
 \newcommand{\bracks}[1]{\left\lbrack\,{#1}\,\right\rbrack}
 \newcommand{\dd}{\mathrm{d}}
 \newcommand{\ds}[1]{\displaystyle{#1}}
 \newcommand{\expo}[1]{\,\mathrm{e}^{#1}\,}
 \newcommand{\ic}{\mathrm{i}}
 \newcommand{\mc}[1]{\mathcal{#1}}
 \newcommand{\mrm}[1]{\mathrm{#1}}
 \newcommand{\pars}[1]{\left(\,{#1}\,\right)}
 \newcommand{\partiald}[3][]{\frac{\partial^{#1} #2}{\partial #3^{#1}}}
 \newcommand{\root}[2][]{\,\sqrt[#1]{\,{#2}\,}\,}
 \newcommand{\totald}[3][]{\frac{\mathrm{d}^{#1} #2}{\mathrm{d} #3^{#1}}}
 \newcommand{\verts}[1]{\left\vert\,{#1}\,\right\vert}$
\begin{align}
\hat{\mrm{f}}_{s}\pars{\vec{k}} & \equiv
\iiint_{\large\mathbb{R}^{3}}{r^{s} \over 1 + r^{2}}\,
\expo{-\ic\vec{k}\cdot\vec{r}}\dd^{3}\vec{r} =
\int_{0}^{\infty}{r^{s} \over 1 + r^{2}}\,
4\pi r^{2}\
\overbrace{\int_{\Omega_{\large\vec{r}}}
\expo{-\ic\vec{k}\cdot\vec{r}}{\dd\Omega_{\vec{r}} \over 4\pi}}^{\ds{\sin\pars{kr} \over kr}}
\\[5mm] &=
{4\pi \over k}\int_{0}^{\infty}{r^{s + 1} \over 1+ r^{2}}\,\sin\pars{kr}\,\dd r =
{4\pi \over k^{s + 1}}\int_{0}^{\infty}{r^{s + 1} \over  r^{2} + k^{2}}\,\sin\pars{r}\,\dd r
\end{align}

> It's still a cumbersome task but some CAS yields

\begin{align}
\hat{\mrm{f}}_{s}\pars{\hat{k}} & =
{1 \over 2}\,\sec\pars{\pi s \over 2}\bracks{%
\sin\pars{\pi s}\Gamma\pars{s}\,{}_{1}\mrm{F}_{2}\pars{1;{1 \over 2} - {s \over 2}, 1 - {s \over 2};{k^{2} \over 4}} - \pi\verts{k}^{s}\sinh\pars{\verts{k}}}
\\[5mm] & \mbox{with}\quad-3 < s < 1
\end{align}

> ${}_{1}\mrm{F}_{2}$ is the [Generalized Hypergeometric PFQ](http://dlmf.nist.gov/16.2.E1).

Comment: Thank you for your answer Felix. What can when $1\leq s<2$? Clearly in that case $f_s$ is not an $L^1$ function anymore, hence the Fourier transform cannot be directly calculated by integrating on $\mathbb{R}^3$.

Comment: @Capublanca I just copied the information from the CAS. I guess it comes from the behavior of $\displaystyle{r^{s + 2} \over r^{2} + k^{2}}$, for fixed $\displaystyle k$, because the $\displaystyle{\sin\left(r\right) \over r}$ integral over $\displaystyle\left(0,\infty\right)$ already exists.